# How to save the information from additionally added fields in CreateUserWizard in separate database, which is different from the Membership database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, createuserwizard

I have the following problem. I am trying to create a web site with the membership authentication and I use the membership data store database to store the information from the CreateUserWizard fields. But I want to add also several more fields(for example FirstName and LastName) to that wizard. I know how to add the fields but the problem is that I can't find information how to store the information from them (i.e. FirstName and LastName) in a separate database, which is different from the Membership database? Is this possible at all? Because I need the membership database for the authentication but I also need my own database where to store additional information which I need for the web site and I need the FirstName and LastName in that database and not in the Membership database?

Could you please help me?

I have searched a lot for information but the only thing that I can find is how to use another table in the Membership database, which doesn't satisfy me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Inorde to store your custom data, you need to make use of, Membership profiles. You find more info over here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e%28en-US,VS.80%29.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx

http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx